# How to have packages' rc config files deleted on package removal?

Tags: configuration, services, delete, software-uninstall, runlevel

Yesterday I noticed the following when I started removing several apps I was not going to use. The file in the rc folders (`/etc/rc0.d` , `/etc/rc1.d`.... `/etc/rc6.d`) associated with the deleted app were still there.

For example, after removing gammut, the file `/etc/rc0.d/K20gammu-smsd` was still there.

Same for the following I found:

Motion - `/etc/rc0.d/K60motion`
WiCD - `/etc/rc0.d/K20wicd`
HDDTemp - `/etc/rc0.d/K20hddtemp`

And so on. This also applies to other RC levels corresponding to the single user, multi user and shutdown levels.

What do I need to do (Avoiding having to do it manually for each) to remove any trace of the app.

Comment: I thought the `purge` option in apt-get deals with this(?)

Comment: @Rinzwind me too. It did not. Nor did the purge with aptitude.

Comment: Since these are startup scripts, and the filename start `K` instead of `S`, they should have no effect, and shouldn't even slow down the start-up process. (Or am I missing something?) Are you sure you need to remove them at all?

Comment: @EliahKagan yes. The thing is, if the app is not even there, why do I need a process to kill it. Kill what? The ghost of the process? Some kind of zombie evolution?

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Replacing `S` with `K` in the name of an `rcN.d`-style startup script is just the standard way of disabling the service. It's not actually killing anything. Still, your question stands--no files for these services existed in your `rc...` directories before the packages were installed, so there *should* be some automated way to get back to that state.

Comment: @EliahKagan Correct. Can you imagine if I install 10 trillion apps and then delete them. How much would the start up scripts take in space. I could be so bold to say that they would be using... 10MB of space. That's 10MB!!

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Yep, 1 millibyte per app. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8211/discussion-between-luis-alvarado-and-eliah-kagan)

Comment: @EliahKagan May I know whats the matter with the file name starts  K instead of S .Thank you.

Comment: @Jai S starts a service, K kills it.

Comment: I would blame the package maintainer, has you been able to reproduce this with other package?